# codeigniter - inner join errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I want to show when I write payTypeId in view, there is write any name of Payment Type. payTypeId is number string 1,2,3 compares the name in payTypeNameEn such as Package, Deposit etc in view table. How to do equal 2 tables such as paymenttype and payment? When I write payTypeId, there will be name of Payment Type in view table. I did something but it gives me  this error :

> Error Number: 42000/1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1)' at line 3
>
> SELECT `paymenttype`.`payTypeId`, `paymenttype`.`payTypeNameEn`, `paymenttype`.`payTypeNameAr`, `payment`.`paymentType` FROM
>   `paymenttype` JOIN `payment` USING (1)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/erp/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h5 class=""><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Type of Payment:</h5>
                                <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="docFileDocType" required="required">
                                    <option value="" readonly>Select</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($payments as $pay){ ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $pay->payTypeId; ?>"><?php echo $pay->payTypeId; ?></option>
                                    <?php  }?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Controller:

```
$this->db->select('paymenttype.payTypeId,paymenttype.payTypeNameEn,paymenttype.payTypeNameAr,payment.paymentType,');
        $this->db->from('paymenttype');
        $this->db->join('payment' ,'payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeId' AND 'payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeNameEn' AND 'payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeNameAr');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
            $viewData['payments'] = $query->row();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$this->db->select('paymenttype.payTypeId,paymenttype.payTypeNameEn,paymenttype.payTypeNameAr,payment.paymentType');
$this->db->from('paymenttype');
$this->db->join('payment' ,'payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeId AND payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeNameEn AND payment.paymentType = paymenttype.payTypeNameAr');
$query = $this->db->get();
  //echo $this->db->last_query();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
   $viewData['payments'] = $query->result();
   print_r($viewData);
}
else
{
  echo 'No records found !';
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in select view. When I write in view the $pay->payTypeId, I want to see in select where is payTypeNameEn such as Deposit etc.

Comment: Ok use `$query->result()` instead of  `$query->row()`, updated my answer for that

Comment: I did. But same thing. There is nothing in select view. How can I do that?

Comment: your query is not returning any data ,make sure `$query->result();` has data

Comment: did my answer help with the issue mention in the question?

Comment: Yeah I am sure it is true but I dont see in my select any name of payment on payTypeNameEn when I write payTypeId in select view.

Comment: i really don't get it what you said `my select any name of payment on payTypeNameEn when I write payTypeId in select view` is there any field `payTypeNameEn`  in your `payment` table , if some fields are not there in your select just add it to it , i don't know you table structure that is why its difficult for me to do it from this side

Comment: payTypeNameEn and payTypeId fields are in paymenttype table. can we chat ?